# Positioning text or logo over div that disappears on mouse over

Tags: html, css, video

```
<section id="fbsection4"> <!--section with videos filling page-->
<div class="block">
<div id="bl-main" class="bl-main">

<section>
<iframe width="599" height="400"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qyq29EaJD0M?rel=0"class="bl-box fancybox-effects-d" title="" ></iframe>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Ok, so I have a page filled with video content, its a portfolio page with 9 videos on it.  Exactly as above, I have only but 1 video here. On opening the page it looks blank but on mouse over the videos start to appear.  All that is working fine.

What I want to know is can I place some text or an image over each video that will be seen on page load but disappear on mouse over (videos appear on mouse over already) but not reappear while the video is playing.  In fact it should not reappear until the page is refreshed.

Comment: Your question has #html and #css tags. You search a CSS-Only solution?

Comment: Thanks so much, simple and effective, did exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. To be sure, you used my answer, CSS-Only solution, isn't it?

Comment: yes,thanks but I then tried to take it a little further but with no success

Comment: You couldn't implement this or what was the problem?

Comment: The page has 9 sections, 9 separate videos placed on the page.  I have put all my logos in place and it works fine, once I hover over the #fbsection4 all the logos disappear which is fine, sort of.                                What I actually want to happen is that when I scroll over each individual section the video for that section appears (which it does now) but ONLY that logo should disappear, the other 8 logos should remain in place and only disappear once I mouse over each one individually.

Comment: You have the same id for all the videos? This is not valid html and that is the problem.

Comment: I have tried wrapping each section in a div to try and identify an individual mouse over but when I put a div inside or outside the individual sections it sends the whole page crazy.  Videos disappear or start moving position.

Comment: If i give the sections ids it messes up the page too. Feeling stupid now that I cant get the mouse effect to work on each video individually.

Comment: yes at the moment each <iframe> video has no id

Comment: all are the same, with no id

Comment: each video has now got its own id and each logo has also its own id

Comment: Because you had the style in css for the id!!! Add also a class and put the style on the class. This are basic rules and are not related with the question. I really tried to help you, but you need to arrange your own code a little. Can you please set my response as the correct one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (a semi-transparent overlay):

```
<section id="fbsection4"> <!--section with videos filling page-->
    <div class="block">
        <div id="bl-main" class="bl-main">
            <section style="position: relative;">
                <iframe width="599" height="400"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qyq29EaJD0M?rel=0"class="bl-box fancybox-effects-d" title="" ></iframe>
                <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0; top: 0; width: 559px; height: 20px; padding: 190px 20px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); text-align: center;" onmouseover="this.style.display='none';">
                    [your text here]
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Just to clarify, I've put a `style="position: relative;"` on your innermost `<section>` and I've added a div after the iframe. The rest is unchanged (apart from some indentation because I couldn't help myself ;)).

### --Edit--

As pointed out, inline CSS is generally A Bad Thing. Javascript too in many cases, though in this case I'd argue the simplicity and small code footprint outweighs the ugliness. But here's how I'd separate it out:

**CSS**

```
#bl-main section {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 559px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 190px 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// this relies on jQuery which you can download from jQuery.com
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.overlay').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="fbsection4"> <!--section with videos filling page-->
    <div class="block">
        <div id="bl-main" class="bl-main">
            <section>
                <iframe width="599" height="400"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qyq29EaJD0M?rel=0"class="bl-box fancybox-effects-d" title="" ></iframe>
                <div style="overlay">
                    [your text here]
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cringing a bit at the inline styles and JS.

Comment: Yeah it's worth mentioning that I went for the quick and easy solution - I tend to do this when I'm trying something new, until it works, at which point I separate out the JS and CSS. I still say there's an argument for using "onmouseover" etc instead of jQuery(thing).on(event, function) - at least sometimes - because it's sooo much easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: I totally understand doing it for prototyping something quick. But you lost me at _"easier to debug and maintain"_. I don't see how that's true when you need the same click, mouseover, etc. handler on multiple pages of a website. Define it in one place (separate JS file) and you're good to go for site wide updates.

Comment: Personally I like doing `<div onclick="doSomething()">` and then defining the `doSomething` function in a separate JS file. It's when the onclick handler is _assigned_ in the JS that galls me. Instead of just looking in the source code to see where/how a function was invoked I have to try and wrap my head around a Javascript trace. Nevertheless that's what I put in my answer because it seems to be the norm these days.

Comment: +1 for including best practice. I don't agree that it's more difficult to figure out. As the developer you are aware of what's happening in your application. Sure, one might forget which specific element an event handler was attached to but `var el = document.querySelector( '.target' ); el.addEventListener( 'click', function (e) {}, false );` or `$( '.target' ).on( 'click', function (e) {} );` (_jQuery_) is pretty easy to understand and find. Use named functions vs anonymous functions for easier debugging. Besides, you're cluttering the global namespace by using event attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to have a container element for your videos. Inside that container you have *both* the overlay content and the video.

We use JavaScript to make sure the overlay remains hidden unless the page refreshes.

```js
$('.video-overlay').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.video-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.video-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
}
.faux-video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <div class="video-overlay">
    Some text or image here.
  </div>
  <div class="faux-video">[video placeholder]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS only. You can overlay a div on top of the video.

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/kNMnr/2055/

css

```
#video_overlay {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    min-height:405px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.98);
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:300000;
}
#fbsection4:hover #video_overlay{
  display:none;
}
```

html:

```
<section id="fbsection4"> <!--section with videos filling page-->
<div class="block">
<div id="bl-main" class="bl-main">
<div id="video_box">
    <div id="video_overlay"> Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div>
  </div>
<section>
<iframe width="599" height="400"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qyq29EaJD0M?rel=0"class="bl-box fancybox-effects-d" title="" ></iframe>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Overlay should remain hidden until page is refreshed.

Comment: @hungerstar I don't see that in the question. I see "will be seen on page load but disappear on mouse over ".

Comment: Very last line, _"In fact it should not reappear until the page is refreshed."_

Comment: @hungerstar Oh, sorry. Maybe he updated the question. I will review the code, I suppose...

Comment: @hungerstar Anyway, after the video starts, that overlay is not visible anymore.

Comment: Only if you leave your mouse on the video.